# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root@localhost'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am connecting Java using Eclipse with MySQL db

**CODE**

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DbDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        String s;       
        String uname="root@localhost";
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student";

        String password="Hsun123";

        int i;

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,password);

            Statement st=con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from student_detail");

            if(rs.next()) {

                i=rs.getInt(1);

                s=rs.getString(2);

                System.out.println(i+"/t"+s);
            }           

            rs.close();

            st.close();

            con.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root@localhost'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:935)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4101)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1300)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2337)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2370)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2154)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at database.DbDemo.main(DbDemo.java:13)
```

What should I do to resolve my problem?

Comment: is the password correct for root@localhost?

Comment: I'd try `String uname="root";`

Answer (score 2):

**Instead of using :**

```
 String uname="root@localhost";
```

**Use :**

```
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student";
String userName="root"
String password="Hsun123"
...
try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
...
```

This should work (provided you are setting the valid password)

Comment: Can someone delete the 10 m's that I added. There was a 4 character change I made `usernamename -> username` that didn't meet the 6 character limit. So I thought by adding extra characters, and then deleting them in a separate edit would be a clever way around the rule. Well it wasn't. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are connecting a remote mysql server from your local machine using java see the below steps.

### Error : java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'xxxxx'@'101.123.163.141' (using password: YES)

for remote access may be cPanel or others grant the remote access for your local ip address.

In the above error message: "101.123.163.141" is the local machine IP. So First we have to give remote access in the  ***cPanel-> Remote MySQL®***. Then run your application to connect.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
    "jdbc:mysql://www.xyz.com/abc","def","ghi");  
//here abc is database name, def is username and ghi        
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from employee");  
    while(rs.next())  
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+"  
                      "+rs.getString(3));  
con.close();
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. I think adding % symbol as the host will allow all IPs.

Answer (score 2):

Below queries, execution has fixed my problem:

`sudo mysql`

`mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`

`mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Answer (score 1):

Well, same problem here. I'm using phpmyadmin.

I had to go to `phpmyadmin->users->root->Edit Privileges.`

Then on the field "`Database-specific privileges`" I had to provide privileges for my database.

On the field "`Change password`" I retyped my password (I don't know why I had to do that, maybe a possible bug since i already had one).

On the field "`Login Information->Host`" I put value Any host.

Problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
String password="Hsun123";
```

instead of

```
String password="";
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are suffering from  this problem

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

(using password: YES)

Solution for that is:

Whatever password you are providing on this line in your code

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection( 
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Pravin","root","password");
```

No need to provide this password just insert `""`

Complete Code is:

```
import java.sql.*;  
class TestDB{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
    try{  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(         "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Pravin","root","");  
        //here sonoo is database name, root is username and password  
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from student");  
        while(rs.next())  
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));  
        con.close();  
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a privileged (i.e. neccessary rights) user account with correct password exist in your database. or just creat no password at all

Answer (score 0):

My answer with the new connector for a data base myPhpAdmin :

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/mydb?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql= false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.main.banner-mode= off
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Adding these connectors via Spring.* on my Spring project! Thank you for posting this!

Answer (score 0):

Choose a password like
password = 'Hellobds123@S'

Then run

> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Hellobds123@S';

> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Answer (score -1):

Late answer, but findings can help others :) Faced similar issue, i was trying to connect database from Spring boot application developed using **Eclipse**. Open **Mysql Command Prompt or GUI tool** and run following query.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%your_password%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Also check your **TCP/IP** service for database are enabled or not.